# How to wrap inner content of a paragraph after specific child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have several bios that all look like this:

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt auctor purus, ut cursus quam fringilla id. Suspendisse a libero id mauris faucibus convallis at ut lacus.
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt auctor purus, ut cursus quam fringilla id. Suspendisse a libero id mauris faucibus convallis at ut lacus.
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt auctor purus, ut cursus quam fringilla id. Suspendisse a libero id mauris faucibus convallis at ut lacus.
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt auctor purus, ut cursus quam fringilla id. Suspendisse a libero id mauris faucibus convallis at ut lacus.
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt auctor purus, ut cursus quam fringilla id. Suspendisse a libero id mauris faucibus convallis at ut lacus.
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt auctor purus, ut cursus quam fringilla id. Suspendisse a libero id mauris faucibus convallis at ut lacus.
</p>
```

Not the prettiest text blocks, but they're auto-generated by the system. I need to iterate through each `<p>` and take everything after the first set of break tags and wrap that in something like a `<div>`.

The end result would be:

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt auctor purus, ut cursus quam fringilla id. Suspendisse a libero id mauris faucibus convallis at ut lacus.</p>
```

```html
<div class="theRest">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt auctor purus, ut cursus quam fringilla id. Suspendisse a libero id mauris faucibus convallis at ut lacus.
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt auctor purus, ut cursus quam fringilla id. Suspendisse a libero id mauris faucibus convallis at ut lacus.
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt auctor purus, ut cursus quam fringilla id. Suspendisse a libero id mauris faucibus convallis at ut lacus.
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt auctor purus, ut cursus quam fringilla id. Suspendisse a libero id mauris faucibus convallis at ut lacus.
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt auctor purus, ut cursus quam fringilla id. Suspendisse a libero id mauris faucibus convallis at ut lacus.
</div>
</p>
```

Comment: You could use jquery wrap()
http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: @rpogonyi I attempted to use something involving wrap. http://jsfiddle.net/Ldycs37m/ My results are a bit noobish, I'm afraid.

Comment: You need to add the tags like this

.wrap('<div class="theRest"></div>')

Comment: In my Fiddle above, it's only wrapping the immediate element following the 2nd break tag, not everything after the 2nd break tag. I tried substituting nextSibling for nextAll to no effect.

Comment: Add class="addDiv" to the <p> element and then

$('.addDiv').wrap('<div />');

Comment: Wouldn't that wrap each <p> in a <div> and not the specified inner content?

Comment: You are right about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (inspired of @dave answer):

```
$("p").each(function(){

    // Add a div after the second <br /> (in the current <p>)
    $("br:eq(1)", this).after('<div class="theRest"> </ div>');

    // Split each "child" in an array
    $(this).contents().filter(function(index, elem){

        // Keep only children after the <div />
        return index > 3;

    // Remove and put them into the <div />
    }).detach().appendTo($(".theRest", this));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ewoeoyL/)

Comment: plz add some explanation to your answer. posting code doesn't help anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('p').each(function() {
    $(this).contents(':gt(2)').wrap('<div class="theRest"></div>');
});
```

But it's not a good enough solution.

For prevent your other `p` element be wrapped, You should find from any parent element like below:

```
$('.father').find('p').each(function() {
    $(this).contents(':gt(2)').wrap('<div class="theRest"></div>');
});
```

Comment: The first example seems to go piece by piece, wrapping each thing in the div tag. I wound up with about half a dozen <div class="theRest"></div> within each <p>. The 2nd example unfortunately doesn't do anything.

Comment: On the live site, however, it still wraps each individual thing in the new div. Each line, each <br>, everything gets its own div wrap for some reason.

Comment: maybe there is some different between two html code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$($("p").contents().get(2)).after('<div class="theRest"></div>');
$("p").contents().filter(function(index, element) {
    return index > 3;
}).detach().appendTo(".theRest");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkexkmtj/)

Answer (score 0):

Even though the format returned from server is bad from my standards as it complicates things for the given purpose. However, with some tricks there is still a way to do it.

Explanation: select all nodes, discard the first node because that happens to be the text node, then use jquery wrapAll method to take everything after that node and wrap it up in new div.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qe3bm92e/3/**

```
var txt = $('.txt').contents();
txt.splice(0,1);
txt.wrapAll($("<div>").addClass('red'));
```

You can replace `'.txt'` with `'p'` but it's not a good practice for very obvious reason.